# SQL query for concatenation of columns in defined pattern

Tags: sql-server

Table `employee`:

```
Day Month Year
------------------
23   NOV  1983
NA   NA   1997
25   NA   1987
NA   NA   1991
NA   Jan  1989
NA   NA   NA
```

I need this result:

```
23-Nov-1983
1997
25-1987
1991
1989
NA
```

Query what I am using to get the result.

```
Select Day '-' + Month + '-' + Year as DOB 
From employee
```

Right now it concatenates the result.

How can I achieve the result in above format ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try like iif(Day='NA','',Day+'-')+iif(Month='NA','',Month+'-')+iif(Year='NA','',Year),if your using sql server 2012 and above.

Comment: What **datatype** are your `Year`, `Month`, `Day` columns?? And which **version** (2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017) of SQL Server are you using??

Comment: Using sql server 2014 version. Day, month, year is in string format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Sql Server 2008 or earlier,try this

```
select (case when Day='NA' then '' else Day+'-' end) + (case when Month='NA' then '' else Month+'-' end)+ (case when Year='NA' then '' else Year+'-' end) as DOB from employee
```

Using sql server 2012 or later

```
select iif(Day='NA','',Day+'-')+iif(Month='NA','',Month+'-')+iif(Ye‌​ar='NA','',Year)as DOB from employee
```

Comment: I am using sql server 2014  i tried the second option it gives me incorrect syntax.

Comment: What datatype are your Year, Month, Day columns?

Comment: string is the datatype

Comment: try first method